# Match word with at least one space on either side

Tags: regex

I need to match these occurrences:

- "Component is "
- " in component"
- " for component "

But I can't match this:

- findForward("componentSummary");

Thus, there needs to be **at least 1 space around the word** (inside quotes), either on the left or right, and potentially both.

My regex so far:

```
".*\s?[cC]omponent\s?.*"
```

But this makes both space optional.

Environment: This is in Eclipse IDE, where I have to search for this regex to find relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `\b` regex anchor that only matches at the edge of words.

```
\bcomponent\b
```

This will match:

```
"component"
"component A"
"A component"
"A component is missing"
```

But not:

```
"Acomponent"
"components"
"The components are missing"
```

Answer (score 1):

You say "there needs to be at least 1 space around the word (inside quotes)"

If so, you either need word characters and space characters on one side or the other side of the target in quotes:

```
"[\s\w]+(\b[Cc]omponent\b)[^"\n]*"|"[^"\n]*(\b[Cc]omponent\b)[\s\w]+"
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pC6fE5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ? mark. This is defining the spaces as optional in the regular expression.